# Where to find the source codes of the Android UI components?

Tags: android, android-source

I believe that all the source code in the Android framework could be found in https://android.googlesource.com, but I cannot find the source code of the UI components there, e.g., android.view.View, widgets, etc.

Can somebody tell me where the code is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/. There are a few subdirectories for view, widget and so on.

See the [Github mirror](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/tree/master/core/java/android). In case this goes down or is not up to date you have to [download the Android source](http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html).

Comment: Given link cannot be access now (Gives 410 error). Can anybody update this link please?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way I found to browse android code is http://google.com/codesearch . Try put "android TextView" for example and you will find it very quickly. It has the added benefit of very fast and efficient search.

Note - there is even "Android" link at the left side to limit your searches just to Android. Just noticed it ;).

Disclaimer: My friend from Google, Miguel, developed big part of it ;).

Comment: Thank you so much for providing such a good way to browse the code.